# Calling global handleError function inside catchError RxJs 6 (Migrating from RxJs 5)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

Recently I upgraded my Ionic 3 project to Ionic 4, with this upgrade a several other packages were updated as well (Angular 5 --> 8 and RxJs 5.5 --> 6.5). Most of the changes needed in code are going well but there is one change I cant resolve.

In one of my services I have a function which does an API fetch (GET). Any errors in the fetch (`http GET`) are handled in a global error function. In my old Ionic 3 / RxJs 5~ application this was done as follows:

```
public fetch(): Observable<T[]> {
    let _path: string = this.path; 
    const url = this.getUrl(_path);

    return this.http
        .get(url, this.options)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

The `handleError` function is defined in another service:

```
protected handleError(error: any) {
    const errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';

    this.logger.error('API endpoint: ' + this.path, errMsg);
    this.showErrorToast(); // not async in Ionic 3

    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
```

In my Ionic 4 / RxJs 6 application I am trying to recreate this without success. 
I have read and changed the following:

- `catch` is deprecated and should be replaced with `catchError`
- `Observable.throw` is also deprecated  and should be replaced by `throwError`

So my new implementation looks as follows:

```
public fetch(): Observable<T[]> {
    let _path: string = this.path; 
    const url = this.getUrl(_path);

    return this.http
        .get(url, this.options)
        .pipe(
          catchError(() => { // this line is returning a error
            this.handleError;
          }
        ));  
}

protected handleError(error: any) {
    const errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';

    this.logger.error('API endpoint: ' + this.path, errMsg);
    this.showErrorToast(); // now async in Ionic 4

    return throwError(errMsg); // Changed this 
}
```

However, the `catchError(() =>` is returning the following error:

```
Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<Object>) => ObservableInput<any>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'
```

After trying several other things I am a bit clueless how this could be solved, any ideas or pointers?

**UPDATE**

After implementing a few of the proposed solutions I keep getting the same, but different error then the previous one:

```
 Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<T[]>'.
      The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
        Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'T[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more
```

So after some investigation I came up with this (Using @theMayer proposed solution):

I Changed:

```
return this.http
    .get(url, this.options)
    .pipe(
      catchError(e => {
        this.handleError(e);
        return EMPTY;
      }
    ));
```

to:

```
return this.http
        .get<T[]>(url, this.options)
        .pipe(
          catchError(e => {
            this.handleError(e);
            return EMPTY;
          }
        ));
```

Above change removes the error but I am not sure this is the way to go? The fetch function will loop over multiple other services which define the API endpoints.

Comment: Use `catchError(this.handleError)`

Comment: @fridoo - it will work syntactically, but when referring to a function directly, `this` becomes unbound at runtime (unless they've since fixed that in a later version of typescript/javascript).

Comment: @theMayer Yes, but as the OP used `catch(this.handleError)` before (and I presume everything worked correctly) switching to `catchError(this.handleError)` should work exaclty the same. If you want to preserve the current context you could use `catchError(this.handleError.bind(this))`

Comment: Or you could write `catchError(e => this.handleError(e))` -> but it would need the method signature changed down below.

Comment: OK, so you have a different problem - you appear to not understand what types are involved. Do you have a competent IDE? I recommend visual studio code, with the Angular Language Service installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting tripped up by a syntax change in RxJs 6.  The error message looks confusing, but all it says is that your error handler must return an observable (as all pipeable operators must). It doesn't care what the observable is *of*, however.

So, a simple rewrite is in order (note that `EMPTY` may not be exactly what you need here, but it works in my code):

```
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';

public fetch(): Observable<T[]> {
    let _path: string = this.path; 
    const url = this.getUrl(_path);

    return this.http
        .get(url, this.options)
        .pipe(
          catchError(e => {        // need to capture the 'e' here...
            this.handleError(e);   // pass to your function
            return EMPTY;          // and return empty
          }
        ));  
}

protected handleError(error: any) {
    const errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';

    this.logger.error('API endpoint: ' + this.path, errMsg);
    this.showErrorToast(); // now async in Ionic 4
}
```

Remove this:

<s>return throwError(errMsg); // Changed this</s>

Comment: I implemented this solution but now I am getting a different error, see my UPDATED main post.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use like this:

```
.pipe(catchError(this.handleError);
```

If you want a general soultion for error handling you can use the Angular built-in ErrorHandler. With this you can catch all the errors occurring runtime and you can show a toaster or whatever you want. If you use this approach then you dont need to implement the error catching login in all your services. This will be automatically triggered when something failed.

In your AppModule in providers import your custom error handler service:

```
providers: [{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: RuntimeErrorHandlerService }]
```

Custom error handling service:

```
@Injectable()
export class RuntimeErrorHandlerService implements ErrorHandler {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  handleError(error: any) {
    // Show your toaster or do whatever you want
    const toasterService = this.injector.get(ToasterService);
    toasterService.show(error);
  }
}
```

You can check if it is a http request error or a runtime error. 
Angular documentation: https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler

Comment: This isn’t really what the user is looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you only put function reference inside catchError(), catchError needs to return an observable. try this

```
catchError(e => { 
            return this.handleError(e);
          }
```